# angular directive with list items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am trying to transclude list items into my custom directive.

The template of my 'list' custom directive is simple:

```
 <ul>
     <li>directive item</li>
     <li>directive item</li>
     <li>directive item</li>
     <div ng-transclude><div>
 </ul>
```

I then use my directive like so

```
<list>
    <child-list></child-list>
</list>
```

childList template is simply:

```
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
```

however the end result of the html is all messed up.

```
<ul>
    <li>directive item</li>
    <li>directive item</li>
    <li>directive item</li>
    <div ng-transclude>
        <li>child item</li>
        <li>child item</li>
        <li>child item</li>
    <div>
</ul>
```

Ideally I would like to just use replace: true in my child directive but it complains about no root element so I would have to wrap it in a div which makes the styling mess up.

My end result I want is

```
<ul>
    <li>directive item</li>
    <li>directive item</li>
    <li>directive item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
</ul>
```

Is this possible or do I have to come up with a css solution.

Thanks in advance!

**update** settled for css solution for now

Comment: Can you post your directive code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tdxr26dL/1/ cant get it to work with multiple li's to avoid adding a div or some sort of wrapper

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-transclude as a element itself.  This will keep extra divs and the like out of your final html.  the ng-transclude element will still be present, but it will be 'transparent' to the browser.

the template would end up looking like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>directive item</li>
     <li>directive item</li>
     <li>directive item</li>
     <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
 </ul>
```

check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/officialsounding/tdxr26dL/) as an example

Comment: I see! However I have multiple li's in my directive so I cant use replace true because it gives me the "must have one root element" message. so then I end up having to wrap in something =*( see http://jsfiddle.net/tdxr26dL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Because you're asking to replace the `ng-transclude` element, you could create you're own transclude function in the `link` method in the directive.

First, in your parent template, you would create a custom "replaceable" element in place of the `ng-transclude` element:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="parent.html">
    <ul>
        <li>directive item</li>
        <li>directive item</li>
        <li>directive item</li>
        <span class="replace"></span>
    </ul>
</script>
```

---

Next, include a link method in the parent directive that finds the custom `replace` element and replaces it with your transcluded elements. Notice the transclude calls upon it's contents to unwrap. More on that next...

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() { 
    return {
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'parent.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            elem.find('.replace').replaceWith(transclude().contents().unwrap());
        }
    };
});
```

---

Finally, in your child directive, set replace to false because Angular complains about not having a root element. The transclude method in the parent returns the child directive results (with the root element `child-list`). So, we then jump into and unwrap the contents (the list items); essentially replacing the `child-list` element.

```
myApp.directive('childList', function() {
    return { 
        templateUrl: 'children.html',
        replace: false
    };
});
```

---

**I've updated the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdxr26dL/4/).**

Comment: Fails for me if used in ng-repeat.

[$compile:multilink] This element has already been linked.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$compile/multilink